# TVOS UISearchController keyboard stopping to show

Tags: ios, tvos, uikeyboard

In my TvOS app I have a viewController with UISearchContainerViewController. Here is the tree of views:

[image]

and

[image]

The searchController looks good and work as needed. From this viewController I can go to another one and from there open another instance with initial viewController (with searchController). In this another instance the everything is well too. BUT, when i pop back to the first instance the keyboard disappearing and the tree looks like:

[image]

I think it's because the instance of the system keyboard is shared across the app. But i don't know how to fix that. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private var keyboardContainer: UISearchContainerViewController!
```

---

In initialController I did add

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    keyboardContainer.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

and it seems that fixed the issue.